# Removing text from each element of a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that has strings like `['\t30/30','\t10/10']` because I used regular expressions in some raw input data from a string called grades.

```
number = re.findall(r'\t\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}',grades)
number[:] = [item.replace('\t', '') for item in number]
```

How to I remove the \t in each element of my list "number"? 
The second line gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: @Miraj50 Instead of `lambda x:x.strip()`, you can just pass `str.strip`.

Comment: @tobias_k I vow to never make this mistake again (this is my second!).
`list(map(str.strip,number))` => `['30/30', '10/10']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually can not reproduce your problem. Make sure `numbers` is what you think it is. It seems to be list of lists instead.

```
>>> grades = "bla bla \t23/40 foo bar bla \t12/20"
>>> number = re.findall(r'\t\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}',grades)
>>> [item.replace("\t", "") for item in number]
['23/40', '12/20']
```

Alternatively, you could use `str.strip` to make it a bit shorter:

```
>>> [item.strip() for item in number]
['23/40', '12/20']
```

However, I would instead suggest to use a capturing group in your regex so the `\t` is not even part of the result:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\t(\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})',grades)
['23/40', '12/20']
```

Or use one group for each of the numbers, so you don't have to split them afterwards:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\t(\d{1,3})\/(\d{1,3})',grades)
[('23', '40'), ('12', '20')]
```

Comment: I was waiting for someone to suggest specifying a capture group :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
number = re.findall(r'\t\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}',grades)
final_data = [re.findall('[^\t]+', i)[0] for i in number]
```

When running this code with `number = ['\t30/30','\t10/10']`, the output is:

```
['30/30', '10/10']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['\t30/30', '\t10/10']
no_tabs = filter(lambda x: x != '\t', data)

print(*no_tabs)
30/30   10/10
```